# how to rename datagridView Column

Tags: asp.net

I have something like this sql query : `Select Sum(value) from Database.table`. And i post this in to some gridView in asp.net web form.

```
<asp:gridview id="foo" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false">
    <columns>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="ID" headertext="Identifier" />
    </columns> 
</asp:gridview>
```

this `Sum(VALUE)` don't have `datafield` or i dont know what is this .How to change  `HeaderText of SUM(value) column`

Comment: select Sum(value) as yourColumnName from Database.table

Comment: you cannot change HeaderText property dynamically.

Comment: You can do one thing, instead to mentioning the <Column> you can turn on the Auto Generate Columns property to true and then at the run time you use select statement with ALIAS and then bind the result to the gridView in this way it will display the column and Value aswell and the Header as the ALIAS.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Select Sum(value) AS SomeColumnName and use it as your datafield.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Sum(value) As ColumnName from Database.table
```

Replace ColumnName with any name you'd like to give the column.

Answer (score 1):

You nee to use an `ALIAS` and then use it inside your `DataField`

```
Select Sum(value) AS SumOfValue from Database.table
```

Then

```
<columns>
    <asp:boundfield datafield="SumOfValue" headertext="Identifier" />  // use the alias name here
</columns>
```